# How can I track down the source of this jitter on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, caching

I'm trying to solve the following jitter problem on linux.  I call sendto() in the exact same way with the exact same data 2 million times.  My min/max/average are: min,max,average,1175,14211,1322.858685 .  Those are nanoseconds.  Min is 1175, average is 1323 but the max is 14211 which is +10 times the average.  I don't even include the first call to sendto() to eliminate cache miss issues.  I have eliminated task switches and softirqs and interrupts as potential sources of jitter.  The only remaining sources of jitter, I think, are cache misses which seem unlikely given that this is the only process running on this box so there isn't some other process on another core polluting the L3 cache.  The other potential source is something in the Linux kernel itself but that also seems unlikely given this is UDP so there is no need to keep state.  Even if there is some locking and some cache misses it seems unlikely that would add up to 12000 ns when the average time takes 1322 ns.  Some kind of memory allocation in the kernel could conceivably take that much time though.  How can I further track this issue down?

Edit1:  I removed the memcpy and the results changed a little but the jitter is mainly still there:

```
new max,time is 3029
new max,time is 3746
new max,time is 5287
new max,time is 6043
new max,time is 9882
min,max,average,1837,9882,2087.033864
```

Edit 2:  I removed the sendto() call with a loop doing the memcpy 600 times and the results are:

```
new max,time is 1894
new max,time is 1922
new max,time is 1923
new max,time is 1925
new max,time is 1928
new max,time is 2002
new max,time is 4530
new max,time is 9269
new max,time is 9466
min,max,average,1880,9466,1881.731031
```

Since those results are pretty close to the same it has nothing to do with the sendto() call itself but some other systemic issue.

Here is the setup:

```
uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=UUID=9cd0a310-313a-4445-8594-39a7fc037b1e ro isolcpus=1-11 nohz_full=1-11 rcu_nocbs=1-11 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 intel_pstate=disable

cat /proc/cpuinfo | more
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 62
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v2 @ 2.60GHz
stepping    : 4
microcode   : 0x415
cpu MHz     : 2599.941
cache size  : 15360 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 6
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bt
s rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx
 f16c rdrand lahf_lm arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms
bogomips    : 5199.88
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

... cut off 5 more cores.  I turned off hyper threading but that hasn't mattered.

I compile the following code with: g++ -O2 jitter.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

void udp_send()
{
  struct timespec tpe1, tpe2;

  int sockfd,n;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
  char sendline[1000];

  sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

  bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  // servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.5.51");
  servaddr.sin_port=htons(3000);

  int nIterations = 2000000;
  int64_t *tTime = new int64_t[nIterations];

  int k = 0;
  for( k = 0; k < nIterations; k++)
  {
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tpe1);
      memcpy( sendline, sendline+200, 64 );
      int n = sendto(sockfd,sendline,64,0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
      if ( n != 64 )
        printf("failed to send\n");
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tpe2);
      int64_t t2 = ( tpe2.tv_sec - tpe1.tv_sec ) *1000000000 + tpe2.tv_nsec - tpe1.tv_nsec;
      if ( k > 0 )
        tTime[k] = t2;
  }

  int64_t tMax = 0;
  int64_t tMin = 99999999999;
  int64_t tTotal = 0;
  for ( k = 1; k < nIterations; k++ )
  {
    int64_t t2 = tTime[k];
    if ( t2 > tMax ) { tMax = t2; printf("new max,time is %ld\n", tMax ); }
    if ( t2 < tMin ) tMin = t2;
    if ( t2 > 20000 ) { printf("that took too long,took,%ld\n", t2 ); }
    tTotal += t2;
  }
  printf("min,max,average,%ld,%ld,%f\n", tMin, tMax, tTotal*1.0 / nIterations );
}


int main()
{
  udp_send();

  return 0;
}
```

I run it with this script ( which I took from the linux dynticks project ) ( sudo ./run ) which moves all the interrupts to core 0 and sets up tracing.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Full dyntick CPU on which we'll run the user loop,
# it must be part of nohz_full kernel parameter
TARGET=5 

NR_CPUS=$(getconf  _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)

# Migrate nocb tasks to CPU 0
# Beware, this assume that there is no online CPU > NR_CPUS
for CPU in $(seq $(($NR_CPUS-1)))
do
        PIDS=$(ps -o pid= -C rcuob/$CPU,rcuos/$CPU,rcuop/$CPU)
        for PID in $PIDS
        do
                taskset -cp 0 $PID
        done

done

# Migrate irqs to CPU 0
for D in $(ls /proc/irq)
do
        if [[ -x "/proc/irq/$D" && $D != "0" ]]
        then
                echo $D
                echo 1 > /proc/irq/$D/smp_affinity
        fi
done

# Delay the annoying vmstat timer far away
sysctl vm.stat_interval=300

# Shutdown nmi watchdog as it uses perf events
sysctl -w kernel.watchdog=0

# Pin the writeback workqueue to CPU0
echo 1 > /sys/bus/workqueue/devices/writeback/cpumask

DIR=/sys/kernel/debug/tracing
echo > $DIR/trace
echo 0 > $DIR/tracing_on
# Uncomment the below for more details on what disturbs the CPU
echo 0 > $DIR/events/irq/enable
echo 1 > $DIR/events/sched/sched_switch/enable
echo 1 > $DIR/events/workqueue/workqueue_queue_work/enable
echo 1 > $DIR/events/workqueue/workqueue_execute_start/enable
echo 1 > $DIR/events/timer/hrtimer_expire_entry/enable
echo 1 > $DIR/events/timer/tick_stop/enable
echo 1 > $DIR/events/timer/enable
echo 0 > $DIR/events/net/enable
echo 0 > $DIR/events/sock/enable
echo 0 > $DIR/events/udp/enable
echo 0 > $DIR/events/skb/enable
echo nop > $DIR/current_tracer
echo 1 > $DIR/tracing_on

# Run a 10 secs user loop on target
taskset -c $TARGET /usr/lib/linux-tools/3.13.0-24-generic/perf stat ./a.out > dfa.tmp &
# chrt -f 99 taskset -c 1 ./a.out 
sleep 30
killall a.out

# Checkout the trace in trace.* file
cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/per_cpu/cpu$TARGET/trace > trace.$TARGET
```

Here is the resulting dfa.tmp file:

```
new max,time is 2196
new max,time is 2729
new max,time is 5900
new max,time is 11621
new max,time is 14211
min,max,average,1175,14211,1322.858685
```

Here is the resulting system trace file:

```
# tracer: nop
#
# entries-in-buffer/entries-written: 34361/34361   #P:6
#
#                              _-----=> irqs-off
#                             / _----=> need-resched
#                            | / _---=> hardirq/softirq
#                            || / _--=> preempt-depth
#                            ||| /     delay
#           TASK-PID   CPU#  ||||    TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
#              | |       |   ||||       |         |
          <idle>-0     [005] dN..   733.720555: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
          <idle>-0     [005] dN..   733.720555: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=733280000000 softexpires=733280000000
          <idle>-0     [005] d...   733.720556: sched_switch: prev_comm=swapper/5 prev_pid=0 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=taskset next_pid=1312 next_prio=120
            perf-1312  [005] ....   733.721806: hrtimer_init: hrtimer=ffff880850b53378 clockid=CLOCK_MONOTONIC mode=HRTIMER_MODE_REL
            perf-1312  [005] d...   733.721857: tick_stop: success=no msg=more than 1 task in runqueue

            perf-1312  [005] d...   733.721883: sched_switch: prev_comm=perf prev_pid=1312 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=perf next_pid=1314 next_prio=120
           a.out-1314  [005] dN..   733.721934: tick_stop: success=no msg=more than 1 task in runqueue

           a.out-1314  [005] d...   733.721936: sched_switch: prev_comm=perf prev_pid=1314 prev_prio=120 prev_state=R ==> next_comm=perf next_pid=1312 next_prio=120
            perf-1312  [005] d...   733.722111: sched_switch: prev_comm=perf prev_pid=1312 prev_prio=120 prev_state=S ==> next_comm=perf next_pid=1314 next_prio=120
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   733.722727: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   733.722728: hrtimer_expire_entry: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer now=733280000768
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   733.722731: hrtimer_expire_exit: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   733.722731: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=733284000000 softexpires=733284000000
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   733.722736: tick_stop: success=yes msg=
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   733.722737: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   733.722737: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=734280000000 softexpires=734280000000
           a.out-1314  [005] ....   733.722960: timer_init: timer=ffff88084f8ec1d8
           a.out-1314  [005] d.s.   733.723023: timer_start: timer=ffff8808518d0650 function=neigh_timer_handler expires=4295075867 [timeout=250]
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   733.986838: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   733.986839: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=734044000000 softexpires=734044000000
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   734.487025: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   734.487025: hrtimer_expire_entry: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer now=734044000419
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   734.487028: hrtimer_expire_exit: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   734.487028: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=734048000000 softexpires=734048000000
           a.out-1314  [005] d.s.   734.487029: timer_cancel: timer=ffffffff81efd6a0
           a.out-1314  [005] ..s.   734.487030: timer_expire_entry: timer=ffffffff81efd6a0 function=clocksource_watchdog now=4295075808
           a.out-1314  [005] d.s.   734.487031: timer_start: timer=ffffffff81efd6a0 function=clocksource_watchdog expires=4295075933 [timeout=125]
           a.out-1314  [005] ..s.   734.487032: timer_expire_exit: timer=ffffffff81efd6a0
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   734.487033: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   734.487033: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=734280000000 softexpires=734280000000
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   734.487033: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   734.487033: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=734280000000 softexpires=734280000000
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   734.723117: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   734.723117: hrtimer_expire_entry: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer now=734280000410
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   734.723119: hrtimer_expire_exit: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   734.723119: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=734284000000 softexpires=734284000000
           a.out-1314  [005] d.s.   734.723120: timer_cancel: timer=ffff8808518d0650
           a.out-1314  [005] ..s.   734.723120: timer_expire_entry: timer=ffff8808518d0650 function=neigh_timer_handler now=4295075867
           a.out-1314  [005] d.s.   734.723122: timer_start: timer=ffff8808518d0650 function=neigh_timer_handler expires=4295076117 [timeout=250]
           a.out-1314  [005] ..s.   734.723126: timer_expire_exit: timer=ffff8808518d0650
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   734.723127: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   734.723127: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=735280000000 softexpires=735280000000
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   735.723507: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   735.723508: hrtimer_expire_entry: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer now=735280000448
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   735.723509: hrtimer_expire_exit: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   735.723509: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=735284000000 softexpires=735284000000
           a.out-1314  [005] d.s.   735.723511: timer_cancel: timer=ffff8808518d0650
           a.out-1314  [005] ..s.   735.723511: timer_expire_entry: timer=ffff8808518d0650 function=neigh_timer_handler now=4295076117
           a.out-1314  [005] d.s.   735.723512: timer_start: timer=ffff8808518d0650 function=neigh_timer_handler expires=4295076367 [timeout=250]
           a.out-1314  [005] ..s.   735.723515: timer_expire_exit: timer=ffff8808518d0650
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   735.723516: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   735.723516: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=736280000000 softexpires=736280000000
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   736.452298: timer_start: timer=ffff8800368823e0 function=commit_timeout expires=4295077736 [timeout=1437]
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   736.452533: tick_stop: success=no msg=more than 1 task in runqueue

           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   736.452534: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-1314  [005] d.h.   736.452535: hrtimer_start: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=736012000000 softexpires=736012000000
           a.out-1314  [005] d...   736.452536: tick_stop: success=no msg=more than 1 task in runqueue

           a.out-1314  [005] d...   736.452537: sched_switch: prev_comm=a.out prev_pid=1314 prev_prio=120 prev_state=x ==> next_comm=perf next_pid=1312 next_prio=120
            perf-1312  [005] d...   736.452647: timer_start: timer=ffffffff81d14ae0 function=delayed_work_timer_fn expires=4295076549 [timeout=250]
            perf-1312  [005] d.h.   736.455802: hrtimer_cancel: hrtimer=ffff88087fd4eca0
```

The perf output is:

```
       4223.769000 task-clock (msec)         #    1.000 CPUs utilized          
                 0 context-switches          #    0.000 K/sec                  
                 0 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
             1,129 page-faults               #    0.267 K/sec                  
    10,977,496,067 cycles                    #    2.599 GHz                    
     5,798,270,864 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   52.82% frontend cycles idle   
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend  
    11,756,238,450 instructions              #    1.07  insns per cycle        
                                             #    0.49  stalled cycles per insn
     2,093,679,462 branches                  #  495.690 M/sec                  
        14,232,955 branch-misses             #    0.68% of all branches        

       4.222272487 seconds time elapsed
```

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong.  The jitter is coming from various softirqs and other things that the OS is doing.  I managed to see this by running:

```
sudo trace-cmd record -s 1000 -b 10000 -e all -o trace_1.dat `taskset -c 5 ./a.out > dfa2.tmp`
sudo trace-cmd report -i trace_1.dat > tmp_1.txt
```

The file tmp_1.txt clearly showed things like this:

```
 a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957658: softirq_raise:        vec=1 [action=TIMER]
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957658: rcu_utilization:      Start scheduler-tick
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957658: softirq_raise:        vec=9 [action=RCU]
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957659: rcu_utilization:      End scheduler-tick
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957660: sched_stat_runtime:   comm=a.out pid=3346 runtime=2950209 [ns] vruntime=38264172961 [ns]
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957662: hrtimer_expire_exit:  hrtimer=0xffff88087fd4eca0
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957663: hrtimer_start:        hrtimer=0xffff88087fd4eca0 function=tick_sched_timer expires=33819608000000 softexpires=33819608000000
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957663: local_timer_exit:     vector=239
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957664: softirq_entry:        vec=1 [action=TIMER]
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957666: softirq_exit:         vec=1 [action=TIMER]
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957666: softirq_entry:        vec=9 [action=RCU]
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957666: rcu_utilization:      Start RCU core
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957667: rcu_utilization:      End RCU core
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957667: softirq_exit:         vec=9 [action=RCU]
           a.out-3346  [005] 33832.957668: tick_stop:            success=yes msg=
```

Which I assume is the cause of the jitter.  I tried opening and writing to /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker and that does show up in the trace file but it isn't as helpful as I had hoped.  You can also read /proc/softirqs before and after and see if that points to an issue whenever there is jitter.

I added code to read /proc/softirqs and sure enough every time there is jitter the timer tick count has gone up by one.  The opposite is not true though, sometimes the timer count goes up in /proc/softirqs but there isn't jitter so obviously it depends on what the kernel decides to do when the timer goes off:

```
          HI:,        685
       TIMER:,      33295
      NET_TX:,         12
      NET_RX:,    4030892
       BLOCK:,          0
BLOCK_IOPOLL:,          0
     TASKLET:,      55873
       SCHED:,          0
     HRTIMER:,          5
         RCU:,       7946
slow,11148
          HI:,        685
       TIMER:,      33296
      NET_TX:,         12
      NET_RX:,    4030892
       BLOCK:,          0
BLOCK_IOPOLL:,          0
     TASKLET:,      55873
       SCHED:,          0
     HRTIMER:,          5
         RCU:,       7947
```

Sometimes the RCU count goes up by one but sometimes not.  The timer count always goes up by one.

Here is the latest code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

/*
  g++ -O2 jitter.cpp
  sudo trace-cmd record -s 1000 -b 10000 -e all -o trace_1.dat `taskset -c 5 ./a.out > dfa2.tmp`
  sudo trace-cmd report -i trace_1.dat > tmp_1.txt
*/

#pragma pack( push )
#pragma pack( 1 )
#define MAX_CPUS 6
#define TARGET_CPU 5
typedef struct
{
  char chName[13];
  char chCPU[11*MAX_CPUS];
  char chNewLine[8];
} procSoftIRQLine1;

typedef struct
{
  char chName[13];
  char chCPU[11*MAX_CPUS];
  char chNewLine;
} procSoftIRQLine2;

typedef struct
{
  procSoftIRQLine1 h;
  procSoftIRQLine2 b[30];
} procSoftIRQ;

#pragma pack(pop)
FILE *pFProcSoftirq = NULL;
procSoftIRQ data;

void read_proc_softirqs()
{
  rewind( pFProcSoftirq );
  size_t tR = fread( (char *)&data, 1, sizeof( data ), pFProcSoftirq );
  size_t nP = sizeof( data.h );
  for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof( data.b ) / sizeof( data.b[0] ) && nP < tR; i++ )
  {
    printf("%.13s,%.11s\n", data.b[i].chName, data.b[i].chCPU+11*(TARGET_CPU) );
    nP += sizeof( procSoftIRQLine2 ) + 1;
  }
}


void udp_send()
{
  struct timespec tpe1, tpe2;

  int sockfd,n;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
  char sendline[1000];

  sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
  FILE *pF = NULL;

  pFProcSoftirq = fopen( "/proc/softirqs", "r" );
  // pF = fopen( "/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker", "w" ); 

  bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  // servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.5.51");
  servaddr.sin_port=htons(3000);

  int nIterations = 1000000;
  // int64_t *tTime = new int64_t[nIterations];

  int k = 0;
  for( k = 0; k < nIterations; k++)
  {
      // fputs( "#dfa,starting\n", pF );
      read_proc_softirqs();
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tpe1);
      for ( int j = 0; j < 600; j++ )
        memcpy( sendline, sendline+200, 64 );
      /*
      int n = sendto(sockfd,sendline,64,0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
      if ( n != 64 )
        printf("failed to send\n");
      */
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tpe2);
      int64_t t2 = ( tpe2.tv_sec - tpe1.tv_sec ) *1000000000 + tpe2.tv_nsec - tpe1.tv_nsec;
      if ( k > 0 )
      {
        if ( t2 > 10000 )
        {
          printf("slow,%ld\n", t2 );
          read_proc_softirqs();
        // if ( t2 > 10000 )
        //   fputs( "#dfa,slow\n", pF );
        // else
        //   fputs( "#dfa,fast\n", pF );
        // tTime[k] = t2;
        }
      }
  }
}


int main()
{
  udp_send();

  return 0;
}
```

You have to hardcode the value of TARGET_CPU to be the CPU that you are going to run the program on.  TARGET_CPU should be what value you are going to use in taskset -c TARGET_CPU ./a.out > out.txt.

I also did ftrace with  echo function_graph > $DIR/current_tracer and I found out that a lot of the time was spent in the function smp_apic_timer_interrupt in arch/x86/kernel/apic/apic.c so I added code to time how much time was spent in that function and added a system call so I could get the amount of time spent in that function from user space.  Sure enough, most of the missing time was coming from that function but not all.  There are a variety of other functions that also take up some time.

Comment: Whats the result of running this with `mlockall(MCL_CURRENT|MCL_FUTURE)` added in an attempt to eliminate major faults?

Comment: I didn't try that but when I get back from vacation ( in September, doh?! ) I will.  I will say that when I ran the ftrace there were a couple of instances of page fault showing up as a source of perhaps a 10-20 usec interruption but they only happened early on.  The biggest interruption was that call to smp_apic_timer_interrupt in apic.c that I mentioned and it was in the 60-70 usec range so I thought I would focus on that one first.  With the hack to the kernel and the system call I made I could confirm that indeed the smp_apic_timer_interrupt was responsible for 90+% of the time.

Comment: For what it is worth here are some kernel developers talking about this problem:  https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/3/28/92